# Split text into different pieces and assign names to each piece

Tags: r, string, vector, tokenize

I want to split the following song on word 'and' (upper or lower case) and assign each split part its name ("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4)

As a result as I'd type "V1" the R would show me "the itsy-bitsy spider climbed up the water spout down came the rain "

This is what I could do so far:

```
song<-paste("The itsy-bitsy spider Climbed up the water spout Down came the rain And washed the spider out Out came the sun And dried up all the rain And the itsy-bitsy spider Climbed up tspout again")

song<-casefold(song, upper=FALSE)

strsplit(song, "and")

V1<-"the itsy-bitsy spider climbed up the water spout down came the rain "

V2<-" washed the spider out out came the sun "

V3<-" dried up all the rain "

V4<-" the itsy-bitsy spider climbed up the spout again"
```

So then I type V4 in R it gives me the text that was cut out previously.

So when I type V3 in R it gives me the text that was cut out previously:

> V3
>   [1] " dried up all the rain "

I just don't want to manually assign the names to each cut piece, because the real text that I'm working on is huge and it will be impossible to do. I was wondering is it possible to do in R? Thanks :)

Comment: What is wrong with what you already did?  The `strsplit ` already gave you a list of the segements.  Why can't you just use that list?

Comment: strsplit gives a list, but I don't know how to generate a frequency table for each segment? I want to know how many times words are repeated in each segment. for example in V1 it would be: "the" 3, "spider" 1 and so on.